# How to compare values between 2 matrix Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, compare, comparison

I have two matrices - `m1` and `m2`of W rows by W columns. Both matrices are filled only two possible values - either `0` or `255`.

How can I compare both matrices in Python3 so that if:

1. all elements in both matrices at the same coordinate equal to `0` - it will output 'Fit'
2. at least one element in both matrices at the same coordinate equal to `0` - it will output 'Hit'.
3. no elements at the same coordinate equall to `0` - it will output 'Miss'.

**For example**:

*Fit*

```
m1 = [[255,0,255],
      [0  ,0,  0],
      [255,0,255]]

m1 = [[255,0,255],
      [0  ,0,  0],
      [255,0,255]]
```

*Hit*

```
m1 = [[255,0,255],
      [0 ,255, 0],
      [255,0,255]]

m1 = [[255,0,255],
      [0  ,0,  0],
      [255,0,255]]
```

*Miss*

```
m1 = [[0,  255,  0],
      [255,255,255],
      [0  ,255,  0]]

m1 = [[255,0,255],
      [0  ,0,  0],
      [255,0,255]]
```

I wrote this script but sometimes it doesn´t return the expected output.

```
for x in range(w):
                for y in range(w):
                    if(m1[x][y] == 0):
                        ones = ones+1
                        if (m1[x][y] == m2[x][y]):
                            matches = matches+1

            if(matches > 0):
                if(matches == ones):
                    print('Fit')

                elif(matches < ones):
                    print('Hit')
            else:
                    print('Miss')
```

Answer (score 0):

The occasional unexpected output is because the if loop checks for 0 values in m1 alone. Changing that helps. The code below works for all three cases.

```
# m1 = [[255,0,255],
#       [0  ,0,  0],
#       [255,0,255]]

# m2 = [[255,0,255],
#       [0  ,0,  0],
#       [255,0,255]]

# m1 = [[255,0,255],
#       [0 ,255, 0],
#       [255,0,255]]

# m2 = [[255,0,255],
#       [0  ,0,  0],
#       [255,0,255]]

m1 = [[0,  255,  0],
      [255,255,255],
      [0  ,255,  0]]

m2 = [[255,0,255],
      [0  ,0,  0],
      [255,0,255]]

w = 3
ones = 0
matches = 0

for x in range(w):
    for y in range(w):
        if (m1[x][y] == 0) or (m2[x][y] == 0):
            ones = ones+1
            if (m1[x][y] == m2[x][y]):
                matches = matches+1

if(matches > 0):
    if(matches == ones):
        print('Fit')

    elif(matches < ones):
        print('Hit')
else:
        print('Miss')
```

The undesired input sequence can be commented out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `NumPy` to do the elementwise comparison in the following way:

```
import numpy as np    

def find_matches(m1, m2):
    if np.sum((m1 == 0) * (m2 == 0)) == np.sum(m1 == 0):
        print('Fit')
    elif np.sum((m1 == 0) * (m2 == 0)):
        print('Hit')
    else:
        print('Miss')

m1 = np.array(
    [[255,0,255],
     [0  ,0,  0],
     [255,0,255]]
    )

m2 = np.array(
    [[255, 0 ,255],
     [255  ,255,  0],
     [255,0,255]]
    )
find_matches(m1, m2)
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach without any loops, should run super fast. This also doesn't need you to search for 0's and 255's in your matrices. Just simple sum, absolute and difference operations.

```
def results(m1, m2):
    #Take sum of absoute values of the 2 matrices
    compute = np.sum(np.abs(np.array(m1)-np.array(m2)))
    
    if compute==0:
        return 'Fit'
    elif compute==255:
        return 'Hit'
    elif compute==255*len(m1)**2:
        return 'Miss'
    else:
        return 'None'
```

```
print('Case 1: ', results(m1, m2))
#Case 1:  Fit
```

```
print('Case 2: ', results(m1, m2))
#Case 1:  Hit
```

```
print('Case 3: ', results(m1, m2))
#Case 1:  Miss
```